# Accessing private dictionary in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, private

How can I access a private dictionary of one class from another class using `__iter__` and `__next__`

```
class Store(AbstractStore, Displayable):

    def __init__(self, store_name : str) -> None:
        self.__store_name = store_name
        self.__products : dict[Product, int] = {}  # Product is an object , int tells about the 
                                                   # quantity of that product
    def __iter__(self):
        self.__index = -1
        return self
    def __next__(self) -> dict[Product, int]:
        if self.__index >= len(self.__products) - 1:
             raise StopIteration()
        self.__index += 1
        #part = self.__products[self.__index]
        product : dict[Product, int] = {}
   # This is only giving me the value , how can I get the key? This method works when I want to 
   #access a private list

        product = self.__products[self.__index]
        return product

class Bookstore(Store):
    def get_products_high_price(self, limit:float) -> list[Product]:
        products : list[Product] = []
        for product in self: 
        # I want to access the private dictionary over here
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `.values()` or `.items()`? Iterating over a dictionary will always only return the keys...

Comment: I am looking for both the key and value

Comment: You need to understand the concept of the dictionary object and the iterator. It's wrong to do ```__products[index]```, while you defined the product as the key of the dictionary. Anyway, why not just defining a method that returns ```__products.items()```?

Comment: there is no 'private' in Python. You should not use double-underscore for storename and products. Double underscore is used for name mangling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over a class you just need to define the __getitem__ method.
Some information was missing from your question or wasn't too clear so I've filled the gaps with what I tought was correct.
So each iteration on the Store class will return the key value pair and the __init__ method stores the products in ascending order starting at zero.

Now your Store class becomes

```
class Store:
    def __init__(self, store_name, products):
        self._store_name = store_name
        self._products = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(products)}

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item in self._products:
            member = item, self._products[item]
            return member
        raise StopIteration
```

now your Bookstore class can iterate its products like this

```
class Bookstore(Store):
    def get_products_high_price(self):
        products = []
        for product in self:
            products += (product,)
        return products
```

I ran the following code

```
my_books = [
    "car manual",
    "boat guide",
    "bike races",
    "skate tournaments",
    "planes to fly",
]
my_store = Bookstore("best store", my_books)
print(my_store.get_products_high_price())
```

and got this result
`[(0, 'car manual'), (1, 'boat guide'), (2, 'bike races'), (3, 'skate tournaments'), (4, 'planes to fly')]`

If there's anything I misunderstood, please let me know so I can fix it.